# Unity Shader Invalid Subscript 'boxMax'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, shader

My error is this:

> Shader error in 'Volund/Standard Character (Specular) ' : invalid subscript 'boxMax' at Assets/Features/Shared/Volund_UnityStandardCore.cginc(261) (on d3d11)
>
> Compiling Vertex program with DIRECTIONAL _NORMALMAP _SPECGLOSSMAP
>
> Platform defines: UNITY_NO_DXT5nm UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_NO_SCREENSPACE_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDf2 SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER3 UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA

I pasted the full error above so please do see it.

And Below is my code of the shader:

```
d.boxMax[0] = unity_SpecCube0_BoxMax;
d.boxMin[0] = unity_SpecCube0_BoxMin;
d.probePosition[0] = unity_SpecCube0_ProbePosition;
d.probeHDR[0] = unity_SpecCube0_HDR;

d.boxMax[1] = unity_SpecCube1_BoxMax;
d.boxMin[1] = unity_SpecCube1_BoxMin;
d.probePosition[1] = unity_SpecCube1_ProbePosition;
d.probeHDR[1] = unity_SpecCube1_HDR;
```

Now i changed it to this

```
#if UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING || UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION
    d.boxMin[0] = unity_SpecCube0_BoxMin;
    d.boxMin[1] = unity_SpecCube1_BoxMin;
#endif


#if UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION
    d.boxMax[0] = unity_SpecCube0_BoxMax;
    d.boxMax[1] = unity_SpecCube1_BoxMax;
    d.probePosition[0] = unity_SpecCube0_ProbePosition;
    d.probePosition[1] = unity_SpecCube1_ProbePosition;
```

> error now: variable d used without having been completely initialized.

What my problem here is i successfully converted my .exe application to .apk application but the when i opened it on my device it's just a dark screen and it show the error above after i build it. What could be the problem? Cause i'm speculating that the error above is cause.

Comment: I tried doing this UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(UnityGIInput, d); still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I just want to share what i did here

```
UnityGIInput d;
UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(UnityGIInput, d);
d.light = light;
d.worldPos = posWorld;
d.worldViewDir = -eyeVec;
d.atten = atten;
#if defined(LIGHTMAP_ON) || defined(DYNAMICLIGHTMAP_ON)
    d.ambient = 0;
    d.lightmapUV = i_ambientOrLightmapUV;
#else
    d.ambient = i_ambientOrLightmapUV.rgb;
    d.lightmapUV = 0;
#endif

#if UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING || UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION
    d.boxMin[0] = unity_SpecCube0_BoxMin; // .w holds lerp value for blending
#endif

#if UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION
    d.boxMax[0] = unity_SpecCube0_BoxMax;
    d.probePosition[0] = unity_SpecCube0_ProbePosition;
    d.boxMax[1] = unity_SpecCube1_BoxMax;
    d.boxMin[1] = unity_SpecCube1_BoxMin;
    d.probePosition[1] = unity_SpecCube1_ProbePosition;
#endif
```

Comment: UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(UnityGIInput, d). after UnityGIInput d; line worked for me. Thanks.